# Adding a css class to server control using extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**What I currently have** is this extension method (untested):

```
public static void AddClass(this TextBox control, string newClass)
{
    control.CssClass += " " + newClass;
}
```

I'm narrowing it down to textboxes just to be able to access the `CssClass` property in this example.

**What I'm looking for:**

Making it applicable on all `Control`s with the `CssClass` property. Is this possible?

Comment: It should probably be `control.CssClass += " " + newClass;` Now you are duplicating previous content every time you add a new class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is the base type asp controls are derived from:

```
public static void AddClass(this WebControl control, string newClass)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.CssClass))
    {
         control.CssClass += " " + newClass;
    }
    else
    {
       control.CssClass = newClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, but I don't like your empty check. It should allow you to add a class regardless on whether if classes exist already. I ended up with this: `if (!control.CssClass.Contains(newClass)) control.CssClass += " " + newClass;`

Comment: `It should allow you to add a class regardless on whether if classes exist already.` - it does, if it doesn't have a class it will fall into the `else` block.

Comment: @Johan All the empty check does is prevent superfluous spaces when there are currently no CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

WebControl instead of TextBox may work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#inheritanceContinued